# WCF Service Returns List of Objects in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to return list of object in WCF , my problem is how do i implement it in my application

```
public List GetConsumer(string transformer, string account) { var search = new List();

    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        var item = new SearchConsumer();
        conn.Open();
        const string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM tblconsumer_account WHERE transformer=@tsf AND accountNumber=@acct";
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tsf", transformer);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acct", account);
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            item.SearchResult = true;
            item.AccountNumber = reader["accountNumber"].ToString();
            item.TrasformerNumber = reader["transformer"].ToString();
            item.Firstname = reader["firstname"].ToString();
            item.LastName = reader["lastname"].ToString();
            item.Address = reader["address"].ToString();
            item.SerialNumber = reader["serialNumber"].ToString();
            search.Add(item);
        }
    }
    return search.ToList();
}
```

iam using this [guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/) as reference, but i have a problem finding properties in my application,like `e.Result.Lastname`, `e.Result.Firstname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following

```
public List GetConsumer(string transformer, string account)
```

to

```
public List<SearchConsumer> GetConsumer(string transformer, string account) {
```

and then update your service reference on your mobile project.

You will then be able to do the following:

```
using(var service = new MyService()) //MyService is the name of your service reference
{
    var searchConsumers = service.GetConsumer(transformer, account);
    //Then loop your list
    foreach(var searchConsumer in searchConsumers)
    {
        //Now access properties
        //searchConsumer.Firstname, searchConsumer.Lastname
    }
}
```

If you only want to return a single object, then you will need to change your signature to the following:

```
public SearchConsumer GetConsumer(string transformer, string account)
```

and change the body of the function to only get one item, the usage for this would be:

```
using(var service = new MyService()) //MyService is the name of your service reference
{
    var searchConsumer = service.GetConsumer(transformer, account);
    //Now access properties
    //searchConsumer.Firstname, searchConsumer.Lastname
}
```

**Edit**

If you are going to use async web service calls you would need to do something like this

```
using(var service = new MyService()) //MyService is the name of your service reference
{
    service.GetConsumerCompleted += GetConsumerCompletedCallback;
    service.GetConsumerAsync(transformer, account);
}

//this method can be auto generated when hitting tab twice in visual studio after adding +=

public void (object sender, GetConsumerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //e.Result.Firstname, e.Result.Lastname
    //or if you are returning a list then loop over using code above
}
```

Comment: hi sir after adding this on my btnSearch Click event `using (var service = new MobileBillingServiceClient())
  {
    var searchConsumer = service.GetConsumerAsync(_txtTranformer.text, _txtAccount.text);
  }`  iam getting an error saying Cannot assign "void" to an implicitly-typed local variable.

Comment: i am getting the error here in this line of code `service.GetConsumerAsync(_txtTranformer.text, _txtAccount.text);`

Comment: It is because you are using the async method.  You will have to add something like `service.CetConsumerCompleted += SomeCallbackMethod;`

Comment: thanks you very much sir, but i cant still access this `e.Result.Lastname`

Comment: is there any alternative to this?

Comment: @armory09 can you post the code you currently have?  As the above ways work (I currently use it like so).

Comment: as i said i cant access the `e.Result.Lastname` properties, i found out that its because the object is in list<T>, to access it you need to loop it with foreach like this `foreach (var item in e.Result){ var lastname = item.Lastname}`, anyway thanks for your help.